# Promise denodeify Joi.validate

Tags: node.js, promise, joi

I've got a question about denodeify and promises. I've got some code (shown below); I'm using Promise@7.0.1 and I wanted to just denodeify Joi.validate. If I do something like

```
var jv = Promise.denodeify(Joi.validate);

return jv(Qs.parse(request.query), joiSchema).then(function(value) {
    console.log("value = " + JSON.stringify(value));
    return reply("OK").code(200);
});
```

And I give it valid querystring arguments (see code below), it works as expected. If I give a rowCount of 30, however, it just hangs. I can't use function(err,value) in my then(), so how can Joi validation errors/messages be handled in a promise chain? Is this possible?

Here's the code that works without the denodeify:

```
(function() {
var Hapi = require("hapi");
var Boom = require("boom");
var Qs = require("qs");
var Joi = require("joi");
var Promise = require("promise");

var hostName = "SEMrush";
var hostPort = 4355;

// Create a server with a host and port
var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: hostPort
});

server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/joiTest",
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        var joiSchema = Joi.object().keys({
            phrase: Joi.string().alphanum().required(),
            rowCount: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(20)
        });

        Joi.validate(Qs.parse(request.query), joiSchema, function(err, value) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("err = " + err);
                return reply(Boom.badRequest(err.message));
            } else {
                console.log("value = " + value);
                return reply("OK").code(200);
            }
        });
    }
});

// Default catch-all route.
server.route({
    method: '*',
    path: '/{p*}',
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        return reply("The requested resource was not found.").code(404);
    }
});

server.start(function() {
    console.log("\r\nService started on port " + hostPort);
});
})();
```

Comment: Do you mean that a rowCount of 30 leads to an error (the promise is rejected, your callback never called, the app hangs…), or that `denodeify` does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can validation errors/messages be handled in a promise chain? Is this possible?

Yes, `then` does take an (optional) second callback for the error case. It will be called when the promise is rejected, if no callback is given the error just bubbles through the chain.

To replicate the behaviour of your original code, you'll need to use

```
var jv = Promise.denodeify(Joi.validate);

return jv(Qs.parse(request.query), joiSchema).then(function(value) {
    console.log("value = " + JSON.stringify(value));
    return reply("OK").code(200);
}, function(err) {
    console.log("err = " + err);
    return reply(Boom.badRequest(err.message));
});
```